# The equations that describe the evolution are:

Tags: sentence-usage, style

I would like to rephrase  this sentence

> The equations **that** describe the evolution are: ...

- in a better sense.
  the word **that** sound miscellaneous.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "miscellaneous"? That doesn't seem to be a standard usage of the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example

> The equations **that** describe the evolution are: ...

is understandable, however it would be phrased as

> The equations **which** describe the evolution are: ...

If you feel "that" or "which" are **extraneous** (not "miscellaneous"), it might be rephrased as

> The equations **describing** the evolution are: ...